# How to modify screen when a button is pressed in gtk3.0?

Tags: c, gtk3

I'm using GTK 3.0 in c language, present I'm working on navigating between screens, each screen contains different structures. can anyone tell me, how to navigate between screens in same window?

Consider these screens as an example.
when a button is pressed in screen1, it should navigate to screen2 in same window.

screen1:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *halign;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Tooltip");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 15);
  
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Button");
  gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(button, "Button widget");
  
  halign = gtk_alignment_new(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(halign), button);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), halign);  

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);  

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

screen2:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *table;
  GtkWidget *button;

  gchar *values[16] = { "7", "8", "9", "/", 
     "4", "5", "6", "*",
     "1", "2", "3", "-",
     "0", ".", "=", "+"
  };

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 250, 180);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GtkTable");

  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 5);

  table = gtk_table_new(4, 4, TRUE);
  gtk_table_set_row_spacings(GTK_TABLE(table), 2);
  gtk_table_set_col_spacings(GTK_TABLE(table), 2);

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int pos = 0;

  for (i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < 4; j++) {
      button = gtk_button_new_with_label(values[pos]);
      gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), button, j, j+1, i, i+1);
      pos++;
    }
  }

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), table);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @saxbophone check it once

Comment: What do you mean by term "screen"? X Window System screen as part of display? What do you mean by "navigate"? Set focus? There are sources of two independent GTK applications, they can not have the same window.

Comment: @dimich  want to link these screens as mobile app, like in mobile when you click on app icon in homescreen  a new screen related to app will open,where home screen and app screen are 2 different sources , like that  I want to implement with above  examples, when a button is pressed on screen1, screen2 should replace screen1 in window.

Comment: So you want to embed window created by one application into widget of window created by another application? I think it is possible either by envolving underlayer subsystem such as X Window System or Wayland, or by creating offscreen window in "screen2" app and transferring its image to "screen1" and events back with some kind of IPC.